# Testing State Objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105257/storing-an-object-in-state-of-a-react-component) and it's helped with my understanding of how to set state correctly, but I'm struggling with the correct format of testing state based on a variable.

For example, I have this `setState` function call with a `newItem` variable:

```
addToSandwich(newItem){

    setState(prevState => {
        return { sandwichItems: {...prevState.sandwichItems, [newItem]: true} };
    });

}
```

And assuming the current state looks like this:

```
sandwichItems: {
    meat: true,
    cheese: true,
    tomato: false
}
```

With `var newItem = "tomato";`

It would result in this:

```
sandwichItems: {
    meat: true,
    cheese: true,
    tomato: true
}
```

---

But I am unable to test for newItem with:

```
var newItem = "tomato";

if (this.state.sandwichItems.newItem === true) {//whatever}
```

I would have to do:

```
if (this.state.sandwichItems.tomato === true) {//whatever}
```

---

**How do I test for a value in state based on a variable's value?**

Comment: If you want to view the state from your browser, I'd recommend checking out the [React DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)

Comment: @JonWarren I currently use the React DevTools and it's been one of the most useful tools for my web dev projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
var newItem = "tomato";
if(this.state.sandwichItems[newItem] === true { }
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I'm going to leave the question up for a bit before accepting, but this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Just by chance, would you know the syntax to go another object deeper? As if tomato was an object as well? Would it be (this.state.sandwichItems[newItem][value])?

Comment: @Jaich that looks right. But you would need to show me an example of the object.